# Moving Content from Galaxy S7 to iPhone X

Tags: applications, ios

Apple Move to iOS app really sucks. It is only available to transfer a few items from Android to iPhone and you have to factory reset iPhone to bring up the app.

So my question is: what is the fastest way to transfer 60G content, including Contacts, WhatsApp, Music and Photos.

Answer (score 0):

> Apple Move to iOS app really sucks. It is only available to transfer a
>   few items from Android to iPhone and you have to factory reset iPhone
>   to bring up the app.
>
> So my question is: what is the fastest way to transfer 60G content,
>   including Contacts, WhatsApp, Music and Photos.

Apple’s made it easy for Android folk to move all of their data from their Galaxy  HTC, or Lenovo phone, etc. i konw some ways:

For contacts: Apple’s official mail app supports iCloud, Microsoft exchange, Gmail, Yahoo,  so if you use one of those services, linking up your email account is pretty straightforward. [Source](https://www.tunesbro.com/transfer-contacts-from-iphone-to-android.html).

For photos, videos.
Apple suggests you use PhotoSync ($3, iOS and Android). You’ll find those freshly synced photos in the Photos app in Albums. You can also move photos and videos with a computer. Download Android File Transfer then go to Transfer > DCIM > Camera to drag the images from your device to a folder on your computer.([source](https://www.photosync-app.com/Downloads.html))

For messages.. sorry, i dind't know.. if you found great way to transfer messages from phone to another phone, please let us know.